# How to fade out a div container inside a closed jQuery Accordion tab

Tags: php, jquery

Hey its really hard to define an exact title for my problem.

I am using jQuery Accordions in my side with the years between 2008 and 2012. Inside these accordions are dates with a hyperlink. If you press any link an ajax get call will follow and append the result into a div container.

If I click the next link the previous one fade out and new div fade in.

Everything works like a charm excpect if I change between 2012 and 2011. Then my last opened div container in 2012 wont fade out.

This is my JS Code:

```
var tempDiv = '';
//Auswahl Jahr zum Anzeigen von Presseartikeln
$("#select_media").live("click", function() {
    var currentPos = $(this).data("pos");
    var currentDiv = $(this).data("div");

    alert(tempDiv);
    $("#" + tempDiv).fadeOut();
    tempDiv = currentDiv;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit.php?action=media_select&pos=' + currentPos,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (select) {
            $("#" + currentDiv).html(select);
            $('#myGallery').galleryView();
            $("#" + currentDiv).fadeIn();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The source Code of media_select is not important all you need to know is that there is an unordered list full of images as response.

This is my Accordion Code:

```
$date = getdate();
        $year = $date['year'];

        for ($i=$year; $i>=2008; $i--) {
            $getID = array();
            $getDate = array();
            $getTitle = array();
            $string = array();

            echo '<h3><a href="#" class="media_year_click">'.$i.'</a></h3>
            <div>';
            $sql = "SELECT 
                        ID,
                        DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d.%m.%Y') AS Date_media,
                        Title
                    FROM 
                        Media
                    WHERE
                        YEAR(Date) = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $i)."'
                    ORDER BY 
                        Date ASC
                    ";

            if (!$result = $db->query($sql)) {
                echo 'Datenbankfehler\n';
                echo $db->error;
            }

            $j = 0;
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $getID[$j] = $row['ID'];
                $getDate[$j] = $row['Date_media'];
                $getTitle[$j] = $row['Title'];
                $j++;
            }

            $result->close();

            //Ausgabe
            if (count($getID) == '0') {
                echo 'Kein Eintrag vorhanden';
            } else {
                echo '<ul id="media_no_point">';
                for($k = 0; $k < count($getID); $k++) {
                    $unique_id = '';
                    $string = explode(".", $getDate[$k]);
                    //Fix wenn Datum Tag 0 am Anfang enthält (wird nicht korrekt an JS übergeben)
                    //05032012 = 5032012 in JS
                    if ($string[0] < 10) {
                        $string[0] = mb_substr($string[0], 1);
                        $unique_id .= $string[0];
                    } else $unique_id .= $string[0];
                    $unique_id .= $string[1];
                    $unique_id .= $string[2];
                    echo '<li><a href="#" data-pos="'.$getID[$k].'" data-div="'.$unique_id.'" id="select_media">'.$getDate[$k].' - '.$getTitle[$k].'</a>
                        <div id="'.$unique_id.'" class="pictures"></div></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
```

If you dont know what I mean visit [my site](http://test.geschichtsverein-bademstal.de/media.html) and click one link in year 2012 and then go to 2011 click the link and go back to 2012. There should be no image gallery.
Inserted alert() to show which div id is set as temp and its showing up the correct id. But the fade out is not working in closed accordion tab.

Edit: So it seems like I cant take any changes of the content in closed Accordion tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue. Added following code:

```
$("#media_accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    //Everytime a new tab is clicked hide previous div container    
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $("#" + tempDiv).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You must hide each vissible gallery on tab click.
Add `class="mygallery"` to the gallery container.

And on tab click just `$('.mygallery').hide();` to hide all galleries, then you can show the one inside the clicked tab

Comment: I only fade out div containers which are previously set to visible (with fade in). Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: yes right but `$('#myGallery').galleryView();` does only create my gallery. Its visible all the time. Thats why i put this into a div container `$("#" + tempDiv);` respectively `$("#" + currentDiv);` So its all hiding in this div and is waiting for a fade in and fade out. I created unique ids for all the divs so that I can call every single one (last one clicked and active one). Im just wondering why fade out wont work after clicking a new year (using accordion)

Comment: Notice that what you are really hiding is the container, not the gallery. When you click again the gallery will be there, visible. If that's not what you want you have to hide both the gallery and the tab

Comment: yes but if the gallery is inside a container which is hidden it should be hidden as well right?#mygallery is used for every gallery on the whole page.Thats why I implemented uniqe div containers. The user can click any link any time and it should always pop up the gallery. And if the user clicks another link the last one should be hidden and new one should pop up. So only just one gallery should be visible for each year. Thats why the code should hide the div (gallery inside) in 2012 before it opens new one in 2011. As you can see on my site the close open problem is working for the same year.

Comment: Edited my answer to see if that helps

Comment: thank you I will give it a try. Any idea how to do a tab call for the Accordion in JS? `$("#media_click_year").live("click", function() { ... });` ? Or is there any other way?

Comment: use $('.mygallery').hide(); right before   $("#" + tempDiv).fadeOut();

Comment: Then im not understanding what you mean, sorry :'(

Comment: np thanks for your help :) I think your idea is just the same like mine implementation (your is just a step simpler). The problem seems to be that I cant make any changes of the content inside a closed jQuery Accordion tabs.